# jQuery cannot get the file part from href attribute

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the href value of an anchor tag using jquery, instead of getting the absolute url, jquery returns just the url without the file part: This is what i mean:

My Html/php

```
$url = "http://localhost/mysite/assets/data.txt";
<a class='view-chart' href="<?php echo $url?>">View Chart</a>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
var url = $('a.view-chart').attr('href');
alert(url);
```

I get this on the alert:

```
http://localhost/mysite/assets/
```

but when I view source on the browser, I see

```
http://localhost/mysite/assets/data.txt
```

But if I do:

```
<a class='view-chart' href="http://localhost/mysite/assets/data.txt">View Chart</a>
```

I get the correct alert message i.e:

```
http://localhost/mysite/assets/data.txt
```

Comment: there is not attr "url", just use attr "href"

Comment: @AlexandruCalin, are you serious? url is the variable that holds the href attr.

Comment: well you just edited... but i know i saw var `url = $('a.view-chart').attr('url');` sorry if i was mistaken otherwise.

Comment: Your code is ok for me...

Comment: What browser you using??

Comment: I remember once I had faced problem when there was a hyphen in the ID field.I dont know if its the issue here.

Comment: @techie_28 did not work event after removing the hyphen

Comment: @Bondye am using firefox 18.0.1

Comment: @AlexandruCalin tomexsans it's true I had used url instead of href, i edited the question

Comment: Are you sure there is only one anchor tag with that class?

Comment: @techie_28 there is more than one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me in localhost

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            var url = $('a.view-chart').attr('href');
            alert(url);
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php $url = "http://localhost/mysite/assets/data.txt"; ?>
     <a class='view-chart' href="<?php echo $url;?>">View Chart</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what is not working for me man

Comment: True @roger its working if i run it as a standalone script. sorry i didn't mention i was using bonfire

Comment: Can you show me an your link somewhere? As I have not worked with bonfire I am not sure now.

Comment: Thanks @Roger. I got it. I have answered the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its working fine

```
<?php 
$url = "http://localhost/mysite/assets/data.txt";?>
 <a class='view-chart' href="<?php echo $url?>">View Chart</a> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var url = $('a.view-chart').attr('href');
        alert(url);
    });
</script>
```

i guess the problem was in work jquery implimentation

Comment: This  is not working too

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url = $('a.view-chart:first').attr('href');
```

if you are looking for the first anchor's href.

Or you need to assign unique Id's to each one of them as you have multiple anchor tags
and then use the ID to get the href.
Like

```
$('#anchrId').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys It worked. THe problem was that there were several links, so I changed the jquery code to this:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Your answers gave me tips.

Comment: Well No one was really clear about your scenario here.You have not mentioned anywhere that you needed it on click of the anchor and the code you wrote is applicable when any of them is clicked.

Comment: if other answers helped you mark them as the solution and upvote them, do not add one your own. also select an answer to mark your question as solved.